# Django View value not updating in template unless gunicorn.socket is restarted (setup: Django + Gunicorn + Nginx)

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, gunicorn

I have a little Django website running on Ubuntu 22.04 on Linode. It uses Nginx and Gunicorn to serve the Django page.

Now I struggle to understand how to get the latest value for today's date & time from views.py upon a page refresh; it seems to get cached somewhere instead.

My view contains the following:

```
import datetime

class MonitorView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
[...]
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_data['todayvalue'] = datetime.datetime.today()
    return context_data
```

And my template contains:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    DummyTitle
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {{todayvalue}}
{% endblock content %}
```

When loading the template, this {{todayvalue}} prints "Aug. 11, 2022, 8:32 a.m.". And when refreshing the template again 10 minutes later, this {{todayvalue}} still prints "Aug. 11, 2022, 8:32 a.m.".

When I restart gunicorn.socket (sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket), the values get updated.

So it seems gunicorn doing some kind of caching. The thing that confuses me even more, is that other values in the views are updated fine in the template without requiring a gunicorn.socket restart. For example this value in the view:

```
total_monthly_sent_volume = DailyStats.objects.filter(sg_date__gt=last_month).aggregate(Sum('sg_processed'))
context_data['total_monthly_sent_volume'] = total_monthly_sent_volume
```

is presented in the template in pretty much the same way, with a `{{total_monthly_sent_volume}}`. This shows a sum, and by refreshing the page you get an upated sum value.

So I guess I have two questions really:

- Why does {{today}} require a gunicorn.socket restart whereas {{total_monthly_sent_volume}} doesn't?
- What's an elegant way of getting the latest value for {{today}} shown in the template without requiring a gunicorn.socket restart?

Thank you!